# Coordinate problems and inverted map

Tags: python, maps, coordinates, latitude-longitude, projection

I'm using the salinity data of ORAS5 and the preview variables and information:

```
salinity =xr.open_dataset('....salinity_ORAS5.nc')
sal = salinity['sosaline']
```

[image]

So, the big problem is each "nav_lon" and "nav_lat" have 2D in x and y. Where in the normal case, for example, the lat data have 1D.

```
sal.nav_lon
```

[image]

In the preview plot, the map is inverted:

```
plt.imshow(sal)
```

[image]

I tried to convert coordinates x/y in lat/lon, but my data continue in 2D, only the values change.

The big question is how to work with my coordinates, with lon (x,y) and lat (x,y)? How transform lon in 0-360 and lat in 0-180? And visualize my map in normal projection, not inverted.

Any help is welcome!

Thank you so much.

**EDIT**

I need a solution to work with the *Projection: Tripolar model grid*.
Or to work a in tripolar model grid or interpolate the data. What is the best manner?

Could someone help me?

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are doing, and so what it is the error: you didn't provide any code. In any case: lat/long is vertical/horizontal. x/y is horizontal/vertical, and geoJSON use long/lat (so horizontal/vertical). Just check careful the origin of your data, and the order or coordinates.

Comment: @Giacomo I need to convert the coordinates into ''real numbers'' (0 to 180 and 0 to 360) and correctly visualize my map, not inverted.

Comment: Yes, but you need to check every step. As you can imagine, there is an error (and it is common to make such errors because what I wrote before). You should just check every step. Because we do not known what you are doing at every step, and which source are you using, we cannot help.

Comment: I don't know if will help, because I just open and plot my data. But I will include the code in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to transform the coordinates in 'normal' lat/lon using CDO.

```
cdo remapbil
```

I hope that helps :)